# Why did my menu disappear when I added styles for my carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, carousel, response-headers

I tried to create two CSS files but it doesn't work. I have joined below my code, HTML, header CSS and Carousel CSS and javascript to create a responsive header.

From the screenshot I have sent can you see what's wrong?
.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwFxC.jpg)
I wanted to create a responsive header with a burger menu and a slideshow carousel below the website header.
There is also another problem, when I remove one of the two CSS file, the menu appears but the links have disapeared and there is only a burger menu. I really need some help to sort this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header> 
        <nav class="navbar"> 
            <div class="navbar-container container">
            <div class="logo-img">  
                <img src="image/logo.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="logo"> 
            </div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accordion menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tab gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>  
    <section aria-label="Newest Photos">
        <div class="carousel"></div>
        <button class ="carousel-button-prev">&#8656;</button>
        <button class ="carousel-button-next">&#8658;</button>
        <ul>
        <li class= "slide"data-active>
          <img src="image/woman-3597095_1280.jpg" alt="woman developer">
        </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="image/web-design-3411373_1280.jpg" alt="web design">
        </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="image/workspace-2443050_1280.jpg" alt="workspace">
        </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="image/code-1076536_1280.jpg" alt="coding">
        </li>
    </ul>
    </section
</body>
</html>
```

```
.logo-img {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: black;

}

.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}



.navbar-links {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 50px;

}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #8379ff;
    border-radius: 15px;

}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
}

.toggle-button {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
}
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide>img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;

}

.slide[data-active] {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 4rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.carousel-button:hover,
.carousel-button:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.carousel-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
    left: 1rem;
}

.carousel-button.next {
    right: 1rem;
}
```

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

First, the fixed version of your code (click on Show code snippet, and then on Run button).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
  const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]
  
  toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

```css
/****** style.css *******/
.logo-img {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: black;

}

.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}



.navbar-links {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 50px;

}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #8379ff;
    border-radius: 15px;

}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
}

.toggle-button {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

.navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
}
/****** style2.css *******/
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide>img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;

}

.slide[data-active] {
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 4rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: 0 .5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.carousel-button:hover,
.carousel-button:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.carousel-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
    left: 1rem;
}

.carousel-button.next {
    right: 1rem;
}
/***** css addition *****/
.toggle-button {
    z-index: 99;
}
.navbar-links {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .logo-img {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home page</title>
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    -->
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <nav class="navbar"> 
            <div class="navbar-container container">
              <div class="logo-img">  
                  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" width="200px" height="200px" alt="logo"> 
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
              </a>
              <div class="navbar-links">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About us </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Accordion menu</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Tab gallery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </nav>
    </header>  
    <section aria-label="Newest Photos">
        <div class="carousel"></div>
        <button class ="carousel-button-prev">&#8656;</button>
        <button class ="carousel-button-next">&#8658;</button>
        <ul>
          <li class= "slide" data-active>
            <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x151" alt="woman developer">
          </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x152" alt="web design">
        </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x153" alt="workspace">
        </li>
        <li class= "slide">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/1000x154" alt="coding">
        </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- </section -->
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Explanations**

1. Your original HTML markup had some errors - the first was an extra closing `div`. The second was an unclosed `</section` . I left both of these inside HTML comments.
2. To make things easier to replicate, I replaced your images with placeholders from [placehold.co](https://placehold.co). Also, the contents of `style.css`, `style2.css`, and `script.js` were simply placed in their respective sections within the Stackoverflow's editor. In order to make it clear where one CSS file ended and another began, I inserted CSS comments - for example `/***** style.css *****/`.
3. I wrapped your original code in an event handler, which waits for the content to load, and then applies appropriate event handlers (`click`, in your case). This isn't absolutely necessary.
4. CSS fix for your missing hamburger icon and links just uses a `z-index` for `.toggle-button` and `.navbar-links` - these were present, but were not visible, because the logo was overlapping with them. Providing the `z-index` placed your menu and the links on layers above the logo. In the code I provided, the fix is at the very bottom of the CSS section of Stackoverflow's code editor.

To meet with your new requirements, I have added a `@media` CSS query. Also, the original CSS near the very end of `style.css` was slightly changed - I've removed the `flex-direction: column` for your `.navbar-links ul`.